# Extended access list conflict condition will it cause override?

Tags: cisco, router, acl, access-control

[image]

```
Corp1(config)# access-list 10 permit tcp 192.168.33.3 0.0.0.0 177.22.242.23 0.0.0.0 eq www
Corp1(config)# access-list 10 deny tcp 192.168.33.0 0.0.0.255  177.22.242.23 0.0.0.0 eq www
Corp1(config)# access-list 10 permit ip any any
Corp1(config)#interface fa0/1
Corp1(config-if)# IP access-group 10 in
```

This is what I came up with I dont have a lab facility or access to packet tracer to test it out.I want to know if the following statement will allow the access to finicial webserver to only host c with IP address 192.168.33.3 and not to the rest of the hosts and if the 2nd and 3rd statement will override the first statement.I was thinking of applying the access list on routers fa interface with .254 IP address .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access lists work on a first-match basis. The traffic will be compared to the list, starting with the first statement in the list. As soon as a match is found, then the router exits the list.